# What are the best practices in building user interface with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uiview, autolayout

I am designing a simple user interface for an app using Xcode and Auto Layout. I have a view controller with three basic outlets: a static image view, a label and a button. You can see it in the picture shown below.

[image: View Controller UI design]

As you can see, I'd like to have the image view horizontally and vertically centered in the view controller, the label just below it and the button somewhere in between the label and the Bottom Layout Guide.

The problem is that I am experiencing some appearance problem with the iPhone 6 I am using for testing. The interface items are not nicely centered as they are supposed to be, as you can see from this screenshot.

[image: View Controller bug in iPhone 6]

I am not asking for the solution to this problem, though. I would rather know whether there are best practices to design a good user interface. For example, is there some way to temporarily hide the label and the button from the view controller to focus only on the debugging of the image view without having to remove and redesign them again?

Comment: Could you please explain why this question deserves a nagative vote? Sometimes it seems to me that this community is working better for people who already know instead of those who have to learn and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the label you want to hide,then uncheck the checkbox **installed**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set its alpha to zero .